# Is it possible to export to body of two different files from main.js?

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, svelte, svelte-component

I want to export components to multiple files from main.js, something like this:

main.js:

```
import Block1 from './Block1.svelte';
import Block2 from './Block2.svelte';

export const Block1  = new Block1({ target: document.body}); //to index.html 
export const Block2  = new Block2({ target: document.body}); //to index2.html
```

How to compile multiple .html files to public directory in svelt js?

Answer (score 0):

I found this repository:

https://github.com/Tom-Siegel/multi-page-svelte

Works well and is possible to add multiple pages as inputs

```
const inputs = [
  "main", //string defaults to input: src/[name].js and output: public/build/[name].js
  {
    input: "src/second.js",
    output: { file: "public/build/second.js", name: "second" },
    css: "public/build/second.css",
  }, //object for setting more specific values for input and output of roolup configuration
];
```